# Preserve case in ConfigParser?

Tags: python, configuration-files, python-2.x, configparser

I have tried to use Python's [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module to save settings. For my app it's important that I preserve the case of each name in my sections. The docs mention that passing str() to [ConfigParser.optionxform()](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.optionxform) would accomplish this, but it doesn't work for me. The names are all lowercase. Am I missing something?

```
<~/.myrc contents>
[rules]
Monkey = foo
Ferret = baz
```

Python pseudocode of what I get:

```
import ConfigParser,os

def get_config():
   config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
   config.optionxform(str())
    try:
        config.read(os.path.expanduser('~/.myrc'))
        return config
    except Exception, e:
        log.error(e)

c = get_config()  
print c.options('rules')
[('monkey', 'foo'), ('ferret', 'baz')]
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The documentation is confusing. What they mean is this:

```
import ConfigParser, os
def get_config():
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform=str
    try:
        config.read(os.path.expanduser('~/.myrc'))
        return config
    except Exception, e:
        log.error(e)

c = get_config()  
print c.options('rules')
```

I.e. override optionxform, instead of calling it; overriding can be done in a subclass or in the instance. When overriding, set it to a function (rather than the result of calling a function).

I have now reported [this as a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue7188), and it has since been fixed.

Comment: Thank you. It works, and I agree that the docs are confusing.

Answer (score 66):

For me worked to set `optionxform` immediately after creating the object

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
```

Comment: Works great! (note that in python 3 it is "configparser" class name (no uppercase)

Comment: @NoamManos: You are referring to the module name (the class name is still [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser)).

Comment: Note that it works too with `ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`

Comment: Indeed. It works. Good to mention that this parameter is not associated essentially to RawConfigParser(), since that it is support as well with ConfigParser() class. Thanks man.

Comment: Note, this kind of monkey patching will generate a `mypy` type error: `Cannot assign to a method`.

Comment: The config you'll never guess yourself :D

Answer (score 17):

Add to your code:

```
config.optionxform = lambda option: option  # preserve case for letters
```

Comment: This appears to work for me at least in python 2.7 and is much cleaner than the accepted answer. Thanks foo!

Comment: this is the same as top scored answer - see line `config.optionxform=str` :) just instead of your lamdba @Martin v. Löwis uses embedded `str` function

Comment: @xuthus - Indeed, you can use 11 lines of code instead of 1 line. As you like.

Comment: This (rather than using `str`) is technically [the method documented in the stdlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.BOOLEAN_STATES).

Comment: Apparently now `str` is the documented way in the docs.

Comment: In fact, BOTH the methods are still documented there.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is answered, but I thought some people might find this solution useful. This is a class that can easily replace the existing `ConfigParser` class.

Edited to incorporate @OozeMeister's suggestion:

```
class CaseConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    def optionxform(self, optionstr):
        return optionstr
```

Usage is the same as normal `ConfigParser`.

```
parser = CaseConfigParser()
parser.read(something)
```

This is so you avoid having to set `optionxform` every time you make a new `ConfigParser`, which is kind of tedious.

Comment: Since `optionxform` is just a method on the `RawConfigParser`, if you're going to go as far as creating your own subclass, you should instead just override the method on the subclass rather than redefining it per instantiation: `class CaseConfigParser(ConfigParser): def optionxform(self, optionstr): return optionstr`

Answer (score 4):

Caveat:

If you use defaults with ConfigParser, i.e.:

```
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser({'FOO_BAZ': 'bar'})
```

and then try to make the parser case-sensitive by using this:

```
config.optionxform = str
```

all your options from config file(s) will keep their case, but `FOO_BAZ` will be converted to lowercase.

To have defaults also keep their case, use subclassing like in @icedtrees answer:

```
class CaseConfigParser(ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser):
    def optionxform(self, optionstr):
        return optionstr

config = CaseConfigParser({'FOO_BAZ': 'bar'})
```

Now `FOO_BAZ` will keep it's case and you won't have **InterpolationMissingOptionError**.