# Preserve camel case and comments in config file when using ConfigParser

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am using [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to edit my configuration file, but while updating the value in config file it ends up with removing all comments and converts all option values to lowercase from camelcase.

**My Initial config file:**

```
[Recording]

Record Video = Yes
Type = mp4 

# You can use [low/medium/high] all lowercase
Quality = medium

# The name of recording file.
Name = Recording
```

**My python script**

```
import configparser

CFG_FILENAME = 'config.txt'

cfg = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cfg.read(str(CFG_FILENAME))
cfgfile = open(str(CFG_FILENAME), 'w')
cfg.set('Recording', 'Record Video','No')
cfg.write(cfgfile)
cfgfile.close()
```

**The Output file**

```
[Recording]
record video = No
type = mp4
quality = medium
name = Recording
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Set this Option to preserve the case.
Check here [Preserve case in ConfigParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611799/preserve-case-in-configparser)

```
config.optionxform=str
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-process your config file before parsing with ConfigParser, and post-process the output written by the ConfigParser, then you can update an INI file without removing comments.

I suggest to transform each comment into an option (key/value pair) during pre-processing. Then ConfigParser will then not throw the comments out. During post processing you'd then 'unpack' the comment and restore it.

To simplify the process you may want to subclass the ConfigParser and override the _read and write methods.

I've done this and [posted the CommentConfigParser class in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jip-Hop/d82781da424724b4018bdfc5a2f1318b). It has one limitation. It does not support indented section headers, comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.

```
class CommentConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
"""Comment preserving ConfigParser.

Limitation: No support for indenting section headers,
comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Backup _comment_prefixes
    self._comment_prefixes_backup = self._comment_prefixes
    # Unset _comment_prefixes so comments won't be skipped
    self._comment_prefixes = ()
    # Template to store comments as key value pair
    self._comment_template = "#{0} = {1}"
    # Regex to match the comment id prefix
    self._comment_regex = re.compile(r"^#\d+\s*=\s*")
    # List to store comments above the first section
    self._top_comments = []

def _read(self, fp, fpname):
    lines = fp.readlines()
    above_first_section = True
    # Preprocess config file to preserve comments
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("["):
            above_first_section = False
        elif line.startswith(self._comment_prefixes_backup):
            if above_first_section:
                # Remove this line for now
                lines[i] = ""
                self._top_comments.append(line)
            else:
                # Store comment as value with unique key based on line number
                lines[i] = self._comment_template.format(i, line)

    # Feed the preprocessed file to the original _read method
    return super()._read(io.StringIO("".join(lines)), fpname)

def write(self, fp, space_around_delimiters=True):
    # Write the config to an in-memory file
    with io.StringIO() as sfile:
        super().write(sfile, space_around_delimiters)
        # Start from the beginning of sfile
        sfile.seek(0)
        lines = sfile.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Remove the comment id prefix
        lines[i] = self._comment_regex.sub("", line, 1)

    fp.write("".join(self._top_comments + lines))
```

To also preserve the case of the keys, you'd use it like so:

```
parser = CommentConfigParser()
parser.optionxform=str
parser.read("./config.txt")
```